# If Statements running all three codes

Tags: statements

```cs
using System;
using System.Drawing;

namespace Group_cafe7
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string name, milk, cap, latt, amer;
            int choice;
            char sizeC, sizeL, sizeA;
            double cappucciniosmall, cappucciniomedium, cappucciniolarge, lattesmall, lattemedium, lattelarge, americanosmall, americanomedium, americanolarge, discount;


            Console.WriteLine("Hello, Please enter your name: ");
            name = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine(" Please enter your number of choice ");
            Console.WriteLine(" 1.Cappuccinio 2. Latte 3. Americano ");
            choice = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            if (choice == 1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(" Choose size of choice: ");
                Console.WriteLine(" S, M, L ");
                sizeC = Convert.ToChar(Console.ReadLine());
                cappucciniosmall = 13.50;
                cappucciniomedium = 18.00;
                cappucciniolarge = 25.50;

                if (sizeC == 'S')
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(" Add Hotmilk yes/no ");
                    milk = Console.ReadLine();


                    Console.WriteLine(" Cappuccinio " + cappucciniosmall);
                    cappucciniosmall = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

                }
                if (sizeC == 'M')
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(" Add Hotmilk yes/no ");
                    milk = (Console.ReadLine());

                    Console.WriteLine(" Cappuccinio " + cappucciniomedium);
                    cappucciniomedium = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
                }
                if (sizeC == 'L')
                {

                    Console.WriteLine(" Add Hotmilk yes/no ");
                    milk = (Console.ReadLine());

                    Console.WriteLine(" Cappuccinio " + cappucciniolarge);
                    cappucciniolarge = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
                }


                Console.WriteLine("Hello, Please enter your name: ");
                name = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine(" Please enter your number of choice ");
                Console.WriteLine(" 1.Cappuccinio 2. Latte 3. Americano ");
                choice = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            }

            else if (choice == 2)
            {

                Console.WriteLine(" Choose size of choice: ");
                Console.WriteLine(" S, M, L ");
                sizeL = Convert.ToChar(Console.ReadLine());
                lattesmall = 15.50;
                lattemedium = 20.00;
                lattelarge = 27.50;

                if (sizeL == 'S')
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(" Add Hotmilk yes/no ");
                    milk = Console.ReadLine();


                    Console.WriteLine(" Latte " + lattesmall);
                    lattesmall = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

                }
                if (sizeL == 'M')
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(" Add Hotmilk yes/no ");
                    milk = (Console.ReadLine());

                    Console.WriteLine(" Latte " + lattemedium);
                    lattemedium = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
                }
                if (sizeL == 'L')
                {

                    Console.WriteLine(" Add Hotmilk yes/no ");
                    milk = (Console.ReadLine());

                    Console.WriteLine(" Latte " + lattelarge);
                    lattelarge = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
                }

                else if (choice == 3)
                {

                }

                Console.WriteLine(" Choose size of choice: ");
                Console.WriteLine(" S, M, L ");
                sizeA = Convert.ToChar(Console.ReadLine());
                americanosmall = 17.50;
                americanomedium = 22.00;
                americanolarge = 29.50;

                if (sizeA == 'S')
                {

                    Console.WriteLine(" Add Hotmilk yes/no ");
                    milk = Console.ReadLine();


                    Console.WriteLine(" Americano " + americanosmall);
                    americanosmall = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

                }
                if (sizeA == 'M')
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(" Add Hotmilk yes/no ");
                    milk = (Console.ReadLine());

                    Console.WriteLine(" Americano " + americanomedium);
                    americanomedium = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
                }
                if (sizeA == 'L')
                {

                    Console.WriteLine(" Add Hotmilk yes/no ");
                    milk = (Console.ReadLine());

                    Console.WriteLine(" Americano " + americanolarge);
                    americanolarge = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

                }
            }
        }
    }  
}
```

Comment: How would i do this as an if statement

Comment: create functions to write the code once instead of repeating it. Use parameters to the function(s) if something is changing a bit in the repeated code. Make use of these functions.

Comment: I could *guess* at what programming language this is, but I *shouldn't have to*. Please add a language tag

Comment: Did you think you could implement this as a *single* `if` statement?

Comment: What are the if statements you're stating that are not working? I presume it has to do with the `else if (choice == 3)` that has empty parenthesis following it, but I can't properly assess the problem if it isn't explained